As an atheist, what should I read to understand Judaism?
I am an atheist (i.e., I'm not Jewish by birth or by conversation) but I would like to understand religious Jewish beliefs, and specifically, how Jews both historically and today interpret the Tanakh.
I am also particularly interested in how Jewish interpretations of the Tanakh differ from Christian interpretations of the Old Testament.
What books should I read to understand this better?

What makes you think learning the Talmud academically will help with that?

There are better options than studying Talmud for you to understand Jewish practice and belief. First of all the book To Be A Jew by Rabbi Hayim Haley Donim is a great resource. Additionally the website chabad.org is the largest Jewish website and has lots of information. The talmud itself is a scholarly work which besides the languages it is written in has its own language to be decoded as well. These other options will help you understand more easily.

@RabbiKaii I tried to condense my question a bit to not make it too rambling, but essentially, what I'm interested in is understanding how Jews understand the Tanakh as opposed to, say, how Christians interpret their Old Testament.  If you think there's a better text for this than the Talmud, I'd be open to that.

@Dude Is Chabad.org really the largest Jewish website?

@unixwitch I can think of many better options tbh. The Talmud wouldn't even occur as a recommendation for your purposes, to me at least

@RabbiKaii Should I edit my question to not specifically mention the Talmud?

@unixwitch it might be a good idea, or feel free to head to the chat room

@RabbiKaii Does this seem more reasonable?  I am interested in studying the Talmud, but I understand if that is a more advanced text that doesn't make sense to begin with.

Jewfaq.org is pretty good. I'm not fully clear on whether you want info about Jewish history, jurisprudence or daily practice.

@rosends My primary interest is in how Jews (historically, or today) interpret the words of the Tanakh.  I am less interested in actual daily practise of Jews.

Consider reading about the XY Problem such as https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377/166155 or elsewhere

Sounds like you might be looking for a good Chumash.

A good answer should guide you to one or more resources explaining fundamental Jewish interpretations of the Torah. Be wary of the extremely-popular modernistic movements that seek to eliminate the particularity of Judaism by reducing ancient Jewish tradition to a universalistic, abstract philosophical ideology which is then arbitrarily imposed onto Jewish texts. Also be wary of extremist fringe groups whose beliefs are closer to those of fundamentalist Islam than Judaism. In general, stay away from the extremists.  They don't have the info you're looking for.

Rabbi Benjamin Blech's Idiot's Guide to Judaism -- the orange book; not the yellow "Judaism for Dummies." If you can get your hands on Rabbi Aryeh Kaplan's The Living Torah, his translation and commentary on the Five Books of Moses is outstanding (but does not tell you what to think or feel about the verse, as some do). Kaplan's The Real Messiah reflects the Jewish views towards well, the stuff you've been asking about; If You Were God covers theology. (Recommend anything by Rabbi Aryeh Kaplan.)

The Talmud is a snapshot of how specific elite Jews recorded their thoughts on certain topics for other scholars. While you can see glimmers of the underlying society and how the Rabbis governed the people, it's not the main focus. Jewish practice and thought today is shaped by so much that came after the Talmud, the Talmud isn't so relevant for your goal.
I've seen the Koren Talmud and it is really nice with lots of elucidation, maps, charts, and pictures but the catch with easy to read material is that modern sensibilities and dogma can be projected backwards on the original source material. It has Steinsaltz's commentary.
I recommend this book: There We Sat Down by Jacob Neusner.
But beware! It comes from an era when the best scholarship came from non-Orthodox Jews and may contain info that the Orthodox may not accept.

Not to be confused with the Korean Talmud, which is mostly about fermented cabbage.

I've accepted this answer and I'll have a look for this book, but I'm interested in any other answers as well.  Thanks!

Neusner has a lot of other titles too.

@unix there's no need to accept an answer immediately. If you aren't sure which answer is best yet, just wait to accept. Some even consider deliberately waiting for alternative perspectives best practice since you never know what you'll find

@DoubleAA Understood.  But if a better answer comes along, I can accept that instead, right?  So it doesn't hurt to accept this one in the mean time, if it answers the question.

@מרים on the other hand, if you want more answers, leaving the question open (i.e., with no selected answers) would signal other members that you're still looking for answers.

Try the Artscroll or Metsudah editions of Tanakh for the most faithful translations in modern vernacular.  A great resource for the differences between Jews and Christians specifically is the work of Rabbi Toviah Singer.

I would recommend Rabbi Singer to a Jew caught up in missionary pressures, and Rabbi Michael Skobac to everyone else. Tovia is saving souls, Rabbi Skobac is also doing some of that, and I do recommend his "why Christianity is wrong" style videos, they are not aggressive, and have a bigger focus on comprehensive education on the differences between the religions. OP is looking for education.

Your question has three parts:

I would like to understand religious Jewish beliefs
specifically, how Jews both historically and today interpret the
Tanakh
how Jewish interpretations of the Tanakh differ from Christian
interpretations

To address part two directly, and part one indirectly, I recommend you read a Chumash with translation, commentary, and notes. (Part three is beyond the range of my knowledge.)
The Chumash is the printed book version of the first five books of the Torah. Chumashim combine the Hebrew text of the Torah with niqqud (vowel marks) and cantillation marks. The text is separated into its 54 constituent weekly Torah portions (parashiyyot), together with the haftarah for each portion and commentary on the text. (Source: Wiki)
I recommend you read at least two different versions of the Chumash, with extensive commentary and references. These are not all used in Orthodox synagogues, but they do have extensive commentary and notes.
Reading more than one Chumash will give you perspective on thousands of years of Jewish commentary, exegesis, and analysis.
Three Chumashim are briefly described below. By reading two side by side you will get the most out of different translations and commentaries.
The Metsudah Chumash / Rashi (5 volumes, 1991) Commentary by Rash”i (Rabbi Shlomo Yitzchaki c. 1040 – 1105 CE)
This contains Rashi’s complete commentary on the text of the first five books of the Torah. Its format is line by line translation of the text and Rashi's commentary, with  notes that identify Rashi's sources and identify the textual difficulties Rashi wished to clarify. (Source: Metsudah publisher)
Soncino Pentateuch & Haftorahs (first published 1937) compiled and annotated by the late Chief Rabbi of England, Rabbi Dr. Joseph Hertz.
“From 1936 to 1981, there was one book that united Orthodox, Conservative, and Reform synagogue goers: the Hertz Pentateuch.The English translation and commentary on the Torah by British Chief Rabbi Joseph Hertz 'for use in Synagogue, School, and Home' was a rhetorical masterpiece that melded traditional biblical interpretation with then-modern scholarship.”
(Source: Soncino Publications)
The Steinsaltz Humash compiled and annotated by Rabbi Adin Even-Israel Steinsaltz (1937 – 2020), an Israeli Chabad Chasidic rabbi, teacher,  author, translator and publisher. Rabbi Steinsaltz is famous for his translation of the complete Talmud into Modern Hebrew.
“A one-volume English translation of the first five volumes of Rabbi Steinsaltz’s Hebrew commentary on the entire Tanakh (Hebrew Bible).” (Source: Daily Forward)

I would recommend starting with Isadore Epstein's classic, Judaism: A Historical Presentation. From there, try The Everything Torah Book and maybe Gateway to Judaism.
